# How to query articles a user has commented on?

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to get all articles in which a user has commented but the article itself is created by others.

Here are the models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=False)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000, blank=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Comment(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    body = models.TextField(max_length=10000)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

The query that I use is:

```
mycomments = Article.objects.filter(Q(comment__creator=request.user) and ~Q(creator=request.user)).order_by("-created")[:30]
```

But for some reason it returns many articles in which the user has not commented. So I'm wondering what should be the correct queryset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Article.objects.filter(comment__creator=request.user) \
               .exclude(creator=request.user).distinct()
```

Comment: This one excludes the article creator, but instead returns many instances of an article if the user has commented on it several times. How to make the return values unique?

Comment: Nice one! Thank you Shang